# How to change the font of a color bar?

Tags: plotting, legending, fonts

When using `DensityPlot` or similar, I want to change the font size of both frame labels and the color bar legend, but I can only get the frame labels to work.

Example:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
labels = Directive[FontSize -> 24, Black, Italic];

DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {-1, 1}}, LabelStyle -> labels], 
 LabelStyle -> labels]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend["LakeColors", 
        LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30,     FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}
]
```

More information in [Mathematica 9 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarLegend.html).